# Reading text file: read.table versus read_table

Tags: r, import, read.table, readr, tidyverse

I'm reading a text file from [this webpage](http://academic.udayton.edu/kissock/http/Weather/gsod95-current/OHCINCIN.txt) into R. If I read this data with `read.table` the data is parsed correctly and I get data for all 12 months:

```
url <- "http://academic.udayton.edu/kissock/http/Weather/gsod95-current/OHCINCIN.txt"

temp_df1 <- read.table(url,
                       col.names = c("Month", "Day", "Year", "Avg_Temp"),
                       na = "-99")

head(temp_df1)
Month Day Year Avg_Temp
1     1   1 1995     41.1
2     1   2 1995     22.2
3     1   3 1995     22.8
4     1   4 1995     14.9
5     1   5 1995      9.5
6     1   6 1995     23.8

unique(temp_df1$Month)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

However, if I read this data in with `read_table` it will first appear that it is parsed correctly; however, the double digit month codes (10, 11, 12) are being stripped such that only the first digit is parsed.

```
temp_df2 <- read_table(url,
                       col_names = c("Month", "Day", "Year", "Avg_Temp"),
                       na = "-99")

head(temp_df2)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  Month   Day  Year Avg_Temp
  <int> <int> <int>    <dbl>
1     1     1  1995     41.1
2     1     2  1995     22.2
3     1     3  1995     22.8
4     1     4  1995     14.9
5     1     5  1995      9.5
6     1     6  1995     23.8

unique(temp_df2$Month)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The dimensions of the data are the same; however, I cannot figure out how to import the data with `read_table` to preserve the full *Month* coding.

```
dim(temp_df1)
[1] 7963    4

dim(temp_df2)
[1] 7963    4
```

Comment: I think this has to do with `read_table` beeing _"similar to read.table, but rather parsing like a file delimited by arbitrary amounts of whitespace, it first finds empty columns and then parses like a fixed width file."_. (See `?read_table`). For example, if you reverse the row order (and thus put a month of length 2 upfront), it works as expected.

Comment: Indeed. This has actually been [filed as a bug](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/518)

Comment: The data seems to actually be fixed-width; numbers are left aligned instead of right, which is likely what's causing the problem. You can read it in explicitly as fixed-width: `temp_df2 <- read_fwf(url, col_positions = fwf_empty(url, col_names = c("Month", "Day", "Year", "Avg_Temp"), skip = 200),
                       na = "-99")`

Comment: @alistaire if you look at the issue I linked to above, you'll see that it doesn't matter if the numbers are left aligned or right aligned. The first 100 rows determine the structure of the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_table` doesn't work as expected due to the issue mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40307042/reading-text-file-read-table-versus-read-table#comment67872420_40307042) by [LukeA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327739/lukea). Instead you should use the `read_fwf` function and specify the field lengths to avoid this issue.

```
temp_df2 <- read_fwf(url, 
    col_positions = fwf_widths(c(14, 14, 13, 4), col_names = c("Month", "Day", "Year", "Avg_Temp")))
```

Keep in mind that for `read_fwf`, `col_names` is passed as an argument to `fwf_widths` and not to `read_fwf` itself.

Additionally, with `read_fwf` you can even skip a step, and parse the date as a `Date` object while you are reading it in:

```
temp_df2 <- read_fwf(url,
                  col_positions = fwf_widths(c(41, 4),
                                             col_names = c("date", "Avg_Temp")), 
                  col_types = cols(col_date("%m %d %Y"), col_number()))
```